# Почему неверно работает рекурсивный поиск файлов и папок?

Tags: c++, winapi

Проблема заключается тогда, когда мне нужно найти файлы с определенной маской в подкаталогах, программа просто не заходит в папки, так как маска другая.
Не знаю как решить эту проблему...
Если вводить маску, к примеру, *, то все работает, но если *.sql, файлы из подкаталогов не находит, а лишь в том каталоге, который я указал изначально.
Чуть исправил код, теперь оно выводит много повторений, с чем может быть связано?

```
void SearchingFiles(TCHAR disk[], HWND hList)
{
    DWORD pr = GetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess());
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    HWND hEditMask = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT_MASK);
    HWND hFindButton = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_BUTTON_FIND);

    _tfinddata_t fileinfo;
    _tfinddata_t nFileInfo;
    wstring str;
    wstringstream ss;

    TCHAR path[1000];
    TCHAR mask[100];
    TCHAR fullPath[1000] = TEXT("");
    TCHAR info[1000];

    GetWindowText(hEditMask, mask, 100);

    _tcscpy_s(path, 1000, disk);
    _tcscpy_s(fullPath, 1000, path);
    _tcscat_s(fullPath, 1000, TEXT("*"));

    intptr_t find = _tfindfirst(fullPath, &fileinfo);
    if (find != -1)
    {
        do {
            ZeroMemory(info, ' ');

            if (lstrcmp(fileinfo.name, TEXT(".")) == 0 || lstrcmp(fileinfo.name, TEXT("..")) == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ((fileinfo.attrib & _A_HIDDEN) != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ((fileinfo.attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM) != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ((fileinfo.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) != 0)
            {
                _tcscpy_s(fullPath, 1000, path);
                _tcscat_s(fullPath, 1000, fileinfo.name);
                _tcscat_s(fullPath, 1000, TEXT("\\"));
                SearchingFiles(fullPath, hList);
                _tcscat_s(info, 1000, TEXT("Folder: "));
            }
            else
            {
                _tcscpy_s(path, 1000, disk);
                _tcscpy_s(fullPath, 1000, path);
                _tcscat_s(fullPath, 1000, mask);

                intptr_t nFind = _tfindfirst(fullPath, &nFileInfo);
                if (nFind != -1)
                {
                    do {
                        ZeroMemory(info, ' ');

                        if (lstrcmp(nFileInfo.name, TEXT(".")) == 0 || lstrcmp(nFileInfo.name, TEXT("..")) == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ((nFileInfo.attrib & _A_HIDDEN) != 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ((nFileInfo.attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM) != 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if ((nFileInfo.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) != 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, TEXT("File: "));

                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, nFileInfo.name);
                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, TEXT("  "));

                        auto time = nFileInfo.time_create; //получаем метку времени создания файла
                        TCHAR strtime[256];
                        _tctime_s(strtime, 256, &time); //преобразуем метку времени в строкове представление
                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, TEXT("Create time: "));
                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, strtime);
                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, TEXT("  Size: "));
                        ss << nFileInfo.size;
                        ss >> str;
                        _tcscat_s(info, 1000, str.c_str());
                        ss.clear();
                        str.clear();

                        SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM(info));

                    } while (_tfindnext(nFind, &nFileInfo) == 0);

                    _findclose(nFind);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("File has not been found"), TEXT("Searching"), MB_OK);
                }
            }

        } while (_tfindnext(find, &fileinfo) == 0);

        _findclose(find);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("File has not been found"), TEXT("Searching"), MB_OK);
    }

    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), pr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, нужны два цикла:

- один - по подпапкам в текущей папке - без маски, с рекурсивным вызовом для каждой подпапки,
- второй - по файлам в текущей папке - с маской.

---

> выводит много повторений

Вынесите весь код в `else`:

```
            _tcscpy_s(path, 1000, disk);
            _tcscpy_s(fullPath, 1000, path);
            _tcscat_s(fullPath, 1000, mask);

            intptr_t nFind = _tfindfirst(fullPath, &nFileInfo);
            if (nFind != -1)
            {
                ...
                _findclose(nFind);
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("File has not been found"), TEXT("Searching"), MB_OK);
            }
```

наружу - после

```
    _findclose(find);
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, попробуй сейчас реализовать

Comment: Чуть подправил, но теперь выводит много повторений, не могу разобраться как это исправить...

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!

Comment: @dYndio  Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: "*Очевидно, нужны два цикла*" - ну, не так уж очевидно. Можно одним, и проверять имена файлов на соответствие маске...